# Lebesgue measure of a set bounded by two spheres

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to calculate the three-dimensional Lebesgue-measure of a set bounded by two spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$x^2+y^2+z^2-2z =0;$
$x^2+y^2+z^2 =2;$

I know I should use cylindrical coordinates for substitution, I just can't seem to figure out **how to get the bounds of the integrals** and what the **order of the integrals should be**.
Secondly, does this use the Fubini theorem and what is the correct argumentation for it's use?

Comment: well the radii are $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ respectively...do you have the formulas for cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: yes! &x = r * cos(\alfa), y = r * sin(\alfa), z = z&

Comment: Why use cylindrical coordinates instead of spherical?

Comment: it was really just a recommendation from our professor, I think spherical would lead to not so pretty computations? or do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

We seek to find the following volume$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{2\cos\theta}^{\sqrt 2}r^2\sin\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{1}{3}(2\sqrt 2-8\cos^3\theta)\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi=\dfrac{8\pi(\sqrt 2-1)}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate on how you get the bounds for integrating with respect to $r$? I believe the correct result should be  $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ or am I mistaken?